# Django annotate exclude with Case & When (Conditional Expression)

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2.2`

While making queryset, I want count of related model, based on few conditions like

```
    queryset = self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
        count_videos=Count('video'),
        count_completed=Count(
            Case(
                When(video__status__in=Video.STATUS_LIST_COMPLETED)
            )
        ),
        count_failed=Count(
            Case(
                When(video__status__in=Video.STATUS_LIST_FAILED)
            )
        ),
        count_pending=Count(
            Case(
                When(
                    video__status__not_in=Video.STATUS_LIST_PENDING_EXCLUDE
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Here 3 counts are working, but in last count `count_pending`, I have to count against `exlude()`. i.e., count number of records excluding the passed list.

**How can I use `exclude` with the above statement?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can negate the value we pass to the [**`filter=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id8):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

queryset = self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
    count_videos=Count('video'),
    count_completed=Count(
        'video',
        filter=Q(video__status__in=STATUS_LIST_COMPLETED)
    ),
    count_failed=Count(
        'video',
        filter=Q(video__status__in=Video.STATUS_LIST_FAILED)
    ),
    count_pending=Count(
        'video',
        filter=~Q(video__status__in=Video.STATUS_LIST_PENDING_EXCLUDE)
    )
)
```

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT model.*,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN NOT video.status IN STATUS_LIST_PENDING_EXCLUDE
                  AND video.status IS NOT NULL
        THEN video.id
        ELSE NULL END
    ) AS count_pending
FROM model
LEFT OUTER JOIN video ON model.id = video.model_id
GROUP BY model.id
```

Comment: @AnujTBE: `When(condition=~Q(..), ...)` but this boils down to the same, and is imho less elegant.

Comment: @AnujTBE: Django will generate a query as is shown in the updated answer, so internally it *does* use `When`, but here we omit some "*code noise*".

Comment: can we pass default value like in `Case`?

Comment: @AnujTBE: no, but for `Count`, that does not matter much, since everything except `NULL` counts as one in the `COUNT(..)` aggregate, it does not matter what the values are here. The idea is that `filter=...` already manages to solve a lot of "boilerplate" `Case(When(..),...)`s, only for more complex ones, `Case(..)` has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the reply to a super old question, but this one hits high on searches for this topic. I needed a very similar thing and wanted a count but had some odd conditions I couldn't work out with `~Q` and landed on an annotate that looked like the following. Posting here only for case for someone that happens to need something similar.

I required a count of Reviews completed, and those in progress, but if the `review.status` was UNTOUCHED it wasn't to get counted in the 'in progress' or 'completed' bin. I used Case with the default value set to 1 for the "not" condition (not completed) then wrapped the Case in a Sum as shown. There were about 9 different status's that indicated 'in progress' and I didn't want to name them all.

```
.values(___bunch_of_group_by_fields_here___)\
.annotate(
    completed=Sum(Case(
        When(status__in=[Review.REVIEW_COMPLETE,
                         ], then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )),
    # essentially: ( not (review complete or untouched) )
    # gets all the status between untouched (default first step) and 
    # complete (final status in the workflow for a review) without having 
    # to specify all the in between statuses
    inprogress=Sum(Case(
        When(status__in=[Review.REVIEW_COMPLETE,
                         Review.UNTOUCHED
                         ], then=Value(0)),
        default=Value(1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
```